# Firebase not triggering - $rootScope.$on($firebaseSimpleLogin:login) on page refresh?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

It triggers when I log in, as I log in, but on page refresh it does not trigger anymore? How should I set up a function that would trigger?

It seems that when I refresh the page, it reconnects and re-authenticates (refer firebase log below), but (my guess is) does not fire the

```
0: event:/users:{"ep":"simplelogin:145","sp":"simplelogin:145"}:value
```

What gives?

Thanks
Ryan

CONTROLLER:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ccApp.services.user', ['ccApp.services.auth'])
    .factory('User', ['$firebase', '$rootScope', 'FBURL',
      function($firebase, $rootScope, FBURL){
        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + '/users');

        var users = $firebase(ref);

        var User = {
          create: function (authUser, name) {
            /* jshint camelcase: false */
            console.log(authUser.id);
            console.log(authUser.user);
            users[authUser.id] = {
              md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
              name: name,
              $priority: authUser.uid
            };

            users.$save(authUser.id).then(function () {
              console.log(authUser.id);
              setCurrentUser(authUser.id);
            });
          },

          findByUserId: function (userId) {
            if (userId) {
              return users.$child(userId);
            }
          },

          getCurrent: function () {
            return $rootScope.currentUser;
          },

          signedIn: function () {
            return $rootScope.currentUser !== undefined;
          }

        };


        function setCurrentUser (userId) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUserId(userId);
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, authUser) {
          console.log("trigger userservice - $firebaseSimpleLogin:login");
          var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));

          query.$on('loaded', function () {
            setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
          });
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function() {
          delete $rootScope.currentUser;
        });

        return User;

      }]);
```

FIREBASE LOG -- ON LOGIN (triggers):

```
p:0: Authenticating using credential: [object Object]   firebase.js:34
p:0: {"r":4,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzOTYxODA0MzcsInYiOjAsImQiOnsicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCIsImlkIjoiMTQ1IiwidWlkIjoic2ltcGxlbG9naW46MTQ1IiwiZW1haWwiOiJjYXRlMzBAY2F0ZTMwLmNvbSIsIm1kNV9oYXNoIjoiM2QzOWIyZGU2Yjc1YjAyZWU0MWZlODkwMTQ2NzEwMTgiLCJzZXNzaW9uS2V5IjoiNjE0NTMzOWViZGU0YWQ0MGE4MjY5MzY4ODA2ZjIwNTcifSwiaWF0IjoxMzk2MDk0MDM2fQ.JAKEQH76MD9M4XsIDJDm0RLBuJ5rQzDgd4h1FiHQw78"}}   firebase.js:34
p:0: from server: {"r":4,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{"provider":"password","id":"145","uid":"simplelogin:145","email":"cate30@cate30.com","md5_hash":"3d39b2de6b75b02ee41fe89014671018","sessionKey":"6145339ebde4ad40a8269368806f2057"},"expires":1396180437}}}   firebase.js:34
trigger userservice - $firebaseSimpleLogin:login userservice.js:49
0: event:/users:{"ep":"simplelogin:145","sp":"simplelogin:145"}:value  firebase.js:34
0: event:/users:{"ep":"simplelogin:145","sp":"simplelogin:145"}:value  firebase.js:34
triggered $firebaseSimpleLogin:login authcontroller.js:14
0: event:/users/145:default:value  firebase.js:34
0: event:/users/145:default:value
```

FIREBASE LOG (ON REFRESH) -- Does not trigger

```
p:0: Browser went online.  Reconnecting.   firebase.js:34
p:0: Authenticating using credential: [object Object]   firebase.js:34
p:0: Making a connection attempt   firebase.js:34
c:0:0: Connection created   firebase.js:34
c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://s-dal5-nss-18.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=cc-1   firebase.js:34
c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.   firebase.js:34
c:0:0: Realtime connection established.   firebase.js:34
p:0: connection ready   firebase.js:34
p:0: {"r":1,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzOTYxODA0MzcsInYiOjAsImQiOnsicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCIsImlkIjoiMTQ1IiwidWlkIjoic2ltcGxlbG9naW46MTQ1IiwiZW1haWwiOiJjYXRlMzBAY2F0ZTMwLmNvbSIsIm1kNV9oYXNoIjoiM2QzOWIyZGU2Yjc1YjAyZWU0MWZlODkwMTQ2NzEwMTgiLCJzZXNzaW9uS2V5IjoiNjE0NTMzOWViZGU0YWQ0MGE4MjY5MzY4ODA2ZjIwNTcifSwiaWF0IjoxMzk2MDk0MDM2fQ.JAKEQH76MD9M4XsIDJDm0RLBuJ5rQzDgd4h1FiHQw78"}}   firebase.js:34
p:0: from server: {"r":1,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{"provider":"password","id":"145","uid":"simplelogin:145","email":"cate30@cate30.com","md5_hash":"3d39b2de6b75b02ee41fe89014671018","sessionKey":"6145339ebde4ad40a8269368806f2057"},"expires":1396180437}}}
```

Comment: The login event is taking place before your controller is established and run, so the listener is not attached yet. :( Where is $firebaseSimpleLogin() being invoked? Try storing the reference to that object (e.g. $rootScope.auth?) and then checking $rootScope.auth.user to see if they have already logged in?

Comment: @Ryan W Kan: Did you find the cause for $firebaseSimpleLogin:login not triggering on page refresh? I have your same issue here... :-( Do you think starting a bounty could help?

Comment: @marcoS Yes, I found out what was wrong. It's been a while though but IIRC it was related to angularFire/ firebaseSimpleLogin version. which version are you using?

Comment: AngularFire version 0.7.1, firebaseSimpleLogin version 1.3.0 (the latest, I suppose...)

Comment: @MarcoS Hmm... hard to say what's wrong without code. Mine is behaving as expected now. Perhaps post some codes?

Comment: @Ryan W Kan: I'm sorry... I decided not to care about that issue, continued coding, and now - I don't know how - a page hard refresh keeps my page authenticated... However, I just checked - $firebaseSimpleLogin:login does not fire on a page hard refresh (as it is reasonable...). Probably I did "unconsciosly" solve an issue with *my* code... So, problem solved for me, but I can't be of any help, here, sorry again... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue while following the [thinkster tutorial, part 7](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase).

It was fixed by injecting `User`. Which in the tutorial is literally the next step (hopefully someone might be able to avoid that little roadblock thanks to my stupidity).

But in general what was causing the problem is the fact that the `User` service wasn't injected in any of the controllers on the page, so the `$rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login' ...` listener wasn't being registered, and hence not triggering.